# Mysql suddenly crashed. upgrade_57

Tags: mysql, crash

Mysql suddenly crashed. That what in logs. Can anybody say what happened there?

[image: Mysql crashes]

Comment: your SQL server died in the upgrade section of THD* maybe one or more socket/s is broken ;)

Comment: It mean mysql want to upgrade to a new version and crashed?

Comment: are you using the MySQL version `8.0.4`?

Comment: May be. Now I call yum update and this updated to `8.0.17`. Is there problem with socked in `8.0.4`?

Comment: you should go to 9.0 or higher

Comment: Ok. Will check for further crashes. If it will be again I will try to upgrade. Thank you.